# How to detect if fglrx is installed

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I am working on supporting EGL in my library for context creation and I need some way to detect whether fglrx is installed (so I can fall back to standard glx and `glXCreateContextAttribs`).

Are there any ways I can detect this without simply checking for fglrx specific files and such? I've borked driver installs before and had fglrx files present with mesa installed, so I don't want to have to take that route.